# How to retrive data using Json and Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm having a problem in interpreting this code, I'm developing a seat arrangement Jquery Script. Please help me in interpreting this jquery code

```
setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
    type     : 'get',
    url      : '/bookings/get/100',
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function(response) {
        //iterate through all bookings for our event 
        $.each(response.bookings, function(index, booking) {
            //find seat by id and set its status to unavailable
            sc.status(booking.seat_id, 'unavailable');
        });
    }
});}, 10000); //every 10 seconds
```

Comment: setInterval call $.ajax every 10sec; $.ajax send a request to `{your_domain}/bookings/get/100`; If this url is responding valid JSON the `success` function is called where `response` is the JSON object; `$.each` run a function on each item in `response.bookings`; `sc.status` is some custom function that is called with `booking.seat_id`

Comment: Thank you Philipp, I'm new to Jquery, there is this part I can not really understand. `$.each(response.bookings, function(index, booking) {
            //find seat by id and set its status to unavailable
            sc.status(booking.seat_id, 'unavailable');` would you kindly show me how the JSON object would look like?. I will appreciate your responce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least `response.bookings` can be either an object or an array.
if you what to find you what is you case just run `console.log(response.bookings);` and check the debugger console.

As an object it could look like (i added some fictional fields):

```
var response = {
   status: 'ok',
   bookings: {
   //index: booking
       a: {seat_id: 1, user_id: 4, paid: true},
       b: {seat_id: 2, user_id: 3, paid: false},
       c: {seat_id: 3, user_id: 2, paid: true},
       d: {seat_id: 4, user_id: 1, paid: false}
   }  
};

//$.each means that function is called of each entry of response.bookings
 $.each(response.bookings, function(index, booking) {
     // frist run index='a', booking={seat_id: 1, user_id: 1, paid: true} so booking.seat_id=1
   //second run index='b', booking={seat_id: 2, user_id: 2, paid: false} so booking.seat_id=2
   // third run index='c', booking={seat_id: 3, user_id: 3, paid: true} so booking.seat_id=3
   // fours run index='d', booking={seat_id: 4, user_id: 4, paid: false} so booking.seat_id=4
   sc.status(booking.seat_id, 'unavailable');
   // you can check the values by using console again:
   // console.log(index);
   // console.log(booking);
 });
```

As an array it could look like  (i added some fictional fields):

```
var response = {
    status: 'ok',
  bookings: [
  // array of booking object (index incrementel starting from 0)
    {seat_id: 1, user_id: 4, paid: true},
    {seat_id: 2, user_id: 3, paid: false},
    {seat_id: 3, user_id: 2, paid: true},
    {seat_id: 4, user_id: 1, paid: false}
  ]  
};

//$.each means that function is called of each entry of response.bookings
 $.each(response.bookings, function(index, booking) {
     // frist run index=0, booking={seat_id: 1, user_id: 1, paid: true} so booking.seat_id=1
   //second run index=1, booking={seat_id: 2, user_id: 2, paid: false} so booking.seat_id=2
   // third run index=2, booking={seat_id: 3, user_id: 3, paid: true} so booking.seat_id=3
   // fours run index=3, booking={seat_id: 4, user_id: 4, paid: false} so booking.seat_id=4
   sc.status(booking.seat_id, 'unavailable');
   // you can check the values by using console again:
   // console.log(index);
   // console.log(booking);
 });
```

in general is $.each only a jquery version of an for loop.
Here how you can do it using plain javascript (maybe helps you to unterstand ):

```
// response.bookings is an object
 var booking;
 for (index in response.bookings){
     booking = response.bookings[index];
   sc.status(booking.seat_id, 'unavailable');
   //console.log(booking);
 }

 // response.bookings is an array
 var booking;
 for (var index = 0; index < response.bookings,length; index++){
     booking = response.bookings[index];
   sc.status(booking.seat_id, 'unavailable');
   //console.log(booking);
 }
```